# python google api create folder with permission

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

i am trying to create a public folder in google drive and get in return a link for shareing
this:

```
def createfolder(foldername,service):
    new_role='reader'
    types='anyone'
    # create folder
    file_metadata = {
        'name': '{}'.format(foldername),
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
         'role': 'reader',
         'type': 'anyone',

    }
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                  fields='id,webViewLink').execute()
    print('Folder ID: %s' % file.get('webViewLink'))
    return file.get('id')
```

i got this far
it creates and folder and prints the link 
tryd to add the fields in to the body role and type and set it to reader / anyone but this not working
role type fields seem to be ignored

is there a way to do this on create or do i have to change the permission after i create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You have to call Permissions.create:

File permissions are handled via [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions), not through  `Files` methods.

If you check the [Files resource representation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations), you'll notice that some fields, like `name` or `mimeType`, have the word `writable` under `Notes`. This means you can modify these fields directly using this resource (`Files`) methods.

If you check the property `permissions`, though, you'll notice there's no `writable` there. This means `permissions` cannot be updated directly, using `Files` methods. You have to use `Permissions` methods instead.

More specifically, you have to call [Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) after creating the folder and retrieving its `ID`.

#### Code snippet:

```
def shareWithEveryone(folderId, service):
    payload = {
        "role": "reader",
        "type": "anyone"
    }
    service.permissions().create(fileId=folderId, body=payload).execute()
```

#### Reference:

- [permissions().create(fileId=*, body=None)](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.permissions.html#create)

Comment: thx that work
was hopeing i could do it with one call but this will do :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a folder and changing the permissions are two diffrent calls.

Create your directory first

```
file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata).execute()
```

Then do a [permissions.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update)  To set the permissions on the file to be public.

```
permissions = service.permissions().update(body=permissions).execute()
```

I am not a python dev so the code is a guess

Comment: A `permissionId` would be needed for this (see [method](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.permissions.html#update)). Also, if the file was just created, it only has the default permission for the owner. I don't think this can be updated since it would make the owner to become a `reader`. Permissions.create should be called instead.

Comment: yeah you can update the existing permission,  or you could just create a new one its up to you https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create.

Comment: TBH i will be suprised if you can get a webviewlink on a directory, i have only done this with files before.

Comment: As long as no permission has been previously created after the default one, it's not optional. The existing permission is the default permission, corresponding to the `owner` of this file. You cannot update that permission to share it with `anyone`, since only one account can be `owner` (at least for non-shared drive files), and you cannot update it to any other role, like `reader`, since this would cause the file to have no `owner`. Because of this, when trying to update the default permission with `permissions().update`, an error will be thrown (`fieldNotWritable`).